# iOS UIAccessibility - Is it possible to access elements in dynamically added views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiaccessibility

Is it possible to access accessibility elements inside of dynamically added subviews?

For example, I have a subview that contains and image and some text. After a certain user event, the subview is added for a certain period of time to the main view and then removed. Is it possible for accessibility to access the static text and image inside this "makeshift" subview?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.** Experiment using [VoiceOver](https://www.apple.com/voiceover/info/guide/). If VoiceOver is unable to select the views, you may need to post an notification alerting accessibility clients that [the screen contents have changed](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Accessibility/AccessibilityfromtheViewControllersPerspective.html):

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification,
                                elementToFocusIfAny);
```

If you need the text and image to be selectable, ensure that their container view is *not* [an accessibility element](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSObject/isAccessibilityElement):

```
isAccessibilityElement = NO
```

If you have any further trouble, refer to the [Accessibility Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Introduction/Introduction.html) or return to Stack Overflow with your new question.